# Retrofit 500 Internal server error getting data

Tags: android, json, http-post, retrofit, internal-server-error

I'm just starting out with Retrofit, I'm trying to get data from a server via a @POST request but I keep returning a 500 internal server error.

My aim is to send a user name through request and the server should return a JSON string containing a list of data for given user.

I'm sure its something simple as I'm fairly fresh to using Retrofit, some code below:

my serviceGenerator(uses authentication):

```
private static final String URL = "http://IP address/ProjectZWS/projectzWebService.asmx";

private static RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(URL)
        .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
    if (username != null && password != null) {
        // concatenate username and password with colon for authentication
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        // create Base64 encodet string
        final String basic =
                "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", basic);
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            }
        });
    }

    RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
    return adapter.create(serviceClass);
```

My service class:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/GetData")
    public void GetData(@FIELD String user, Callback<List<Data>> callback);
```

And my main activity code:

```
 InstituteService service = RestService.createService(InstituteService.class, "user", "pass");

   service.GetData("aUser","",new Callback <List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Data> data, Response response) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "success!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Server log:

```
2015-10-31 10:47:02 192.168.1.14 POST /ProjectZWS/projectzWebService.asmx/GetReviews - 80 jeff 176.61.63.95 okhttp/2.5.0 - 500 0 0 1328
```

Request information:

```
Request URL: http://32.17.47.56/ProjectZWS/projectzWebService.asmx/ 
Request path: /ProjectZWS/projectzWebService.asmx/ 
User host address: 176.61.65.876 
User: PC\the pc 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: Basic 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic
```

Thread information:

```
    Thread ID: 10 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.CreateHandler(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Process information:

```
    Process ID: 3288 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Classic
```

Exception information:

```
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Invalid web service call, expected path info of /js/<Method>.
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.CreateHandler(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The server is ASMX, and when the server is sent the GetData method it returns the JSON string with requested data (I have a server guy working backend and he seems happy server is responding fine to the GetData(aUser) command?). The Server is seeing something but it seems like its rubbish?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the error log from the server?

Comment: I dint have the actual log yet but will upload shortly, but the log shows the URL ending at .asmx nothing follows? I just updated the service class (see above) but no success 500 error persists.

Comment: I might be wrong, but you're setting your URL and then set:
@POST("/ProjectZWS/projectzWebService.asmx") where is your service method name?

Comment: is the service name set in my main activity code above as 'service' (see main activity code above)?

Comment: I don't understand, you've created GetData in your service, though I don't see the method you want to invoke. And also You're calling service.GetReviews?

Comment: Apologies, I have corrected above (I changed to getData to try and simplify), ok heres what I have, I have a Method inside the service class GetData. I generate the service and then call GetData from the main activity. Am I missing something else? the server has the method GetData which takes a string user and returns a json list of data. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you specify your service that you want to invoke GetData?
I would expect your URL to be something like:
www.somedomain.com/ProjectZWS/projectzWebService.asmx
and
@POST("/GetData")
public void GetData(@Body String user, Callback<List<Review>> callback);

Comment: Just amended code as per your suggestion but still returning a 500 server error (see edits above).

Comment: Well, if you can get the server's log, I think it might be helpful to further understand the problem.

Comment: added server log, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, issue was in the service class, added @FIELD annotation & added @FIELD annotation and key, value pair in method call and it works a treat. Fully functional code edited in initial post above, below is final fix code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/GetData")
public void GetData(@FIELD String user, Callback<List<Data>> callback);
```